# DATEDIFF in POSTGRESQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, datetime

Hello colleagues I am trying to bring the datediff function from sql server to postgresql with date_part but I can't get it to work, it is for a search filter

sqlserver

```
 OR LOWER(CAST(
        "DATEDIFF(month, USER.USER_FECHA_INCORPORACION, AGENTE.AGENTE_FECHA_RETIRO)" as text))
```

postgresql(What i'm trying)

```
OR LOWER(CAST(
        DATE_PART('month', "USER"."USER_FECHA_INCORPORACION" :: date) 
        - 
        DATE_PART('month', "AGENTE"."AGENTE_FECHA_RETIRO" :: date) as text))
```

Thanks

Comment: Please dont use unrelated tags

Comment: Did you search internet for "plpgsql" "datediff"? There are several implementations, you can easily adapt one...

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres, you could write this with `date_part()` and `age()`:

```
date_part('year', age(user.user_fecha_incorporacionn=, agente.agente_fecha_retiro)) * 12
+ date_part('month', age(user.user_fecha_incorporacionn=, agente.agente_fecha_retiro))
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is to do the calculation based on months:

```
select ( (year(u.USER_FECHA_INCORPORACION) * 12 + month((u.USER_FECHA_INCORPORACION)) -
         (year(a.AGENTE_FECHA_RETIRO) * 12 + month(a.AGENTE_FECHA_RETIRO) )
       ) as diff_months
```